# Can I carry a watch as a gift in my carry-on luggage when flying from Kolkata to Chennai?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, gifts

I bought a new watch for my friend and made a surprise gift pack as well. The watch is an expensive one. I am flying from Kolkata to Chennai and my friend will take it from Chennai and will fly to Bangalore next.

Can I take this watch and surprise gift box in my carry-on luggage?

Is extra tax or custom search needed?

Comment: Are you flying within India? If so customs should not be a problem. In security the box might need extra checking but should not be stopped. This is likely a duplicate of an existing question but I could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

As this is an internal flight within a single country (India), there's no customs. I did a domestic flight this year and can confirm this.

There is security checking, and obviously there's the usual rules around batteries and the like, but a watch should not be a problem at all to take in carry-on.

Comment: India actually has Customs checkpoints at internal state borders as well -- but for cargo, not private travelers.

Answer (score 1):

For domestic flights there is no custom but better carry a purchase bill for that. CISF Guard checks hand luggage where baggage gets checked by the Airline Carrier itself - i.e. putting something in big baggage is less problematic.